# Customer unable to check out on Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento, braintree, personalization

I have an e-commerce platform but recently customers have difficulty check out from the website. When customers proceed to enter payment method credit card, the page just shows loading sign and nothing went through. Checked the back and no error log shows...

I am using Magento 2.2.3, connecting to Braintree.

We recently installed Nosto, and disabled it afterward thinking it might be the cause... any suggestion?

Comment: have you executed setup:upgrade command after emoving your extension ?